# What part in python code is making a syntax error?

Tags: python

```
text=sc.textFile("long")
RDD20172630=text.flatMap(lambda line : line.split()).map(lambda word : (word,1)).reduceByKey(lambda c1, c2 : c1 + c2)
print RDD20172630.sortByKey(ascending=True).collect()
print RDD20172630.map(lambda (w,c): (c,w)).sortByKey(ascending=False).collect()
```

The result to this code comes out as an error as follows:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-14309b0de61d>", line 3
    print RDD20172630.sortByKey(ascending=True).collect()
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: It looks like it is the one < 3.6

Comment: It looks like mess. Code is written in old python2.7 (no brackets around `print` argument). And interpreter looks like 3.x - so you get error.

Answer (score 0):

You're coding in a Python 2.x style, but the interpreter is 3.x.

You should refactor your code so it's 3.x compliant. I wouldn't recommend downgrading your Python version, [as Python 2.7 is reaching end of life/support soon](https://pythonclock.org/)

---

If you (for some reason) want to have your code running on both Python 2.x and 3.x, then consider adding the following line at the start of your file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

And then change **all** your `print` statements, to be `print` calls:

```
print(RDD20172630.sortByKey(ascending=True).collect())
print(RDD20172630.map(lambda (w,c): (c,w)).sortByKey(ascending=False).collect())
```

Please note that the above solution specifically addresses your `SyntaxError`, you might still encounter runtime failures, refer to the [porting guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) for additional help.